# Как работать с git через phpshtorm?

Tags: bitbucket, git, phpstorm, php

На локальном компьютере создана папка для проекта, ее можно коммитить на git сервер.
Как настроить phpstorm для работы с этой папкой и коммитов?
Каждый раз я должен получать данные с сервера на локальный комрьютер(последние коммиты), чтобы продолжить работу?

Comment: > Каждый раз я должен получать данные с сервера на локальный комрьютер(последние коммиты), чтобы продолжить работу?

нет. Выкачивайте их тогда, когда они Вам нужны.

> ее можно коммитить на git сервер

нельзя:) во первых, в git коммитят локально, а потом пушат на сервер. А во-вторых, просто папку нельзя закомитить и запушить. Только файлы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы открыли проект, который под гитом, то в PHPStorm-е появятся [новые кнопки](http://clip2net.com/s/3d78IEJ) на тулбаре. При нажатии на синюю стрелку стянутся последние коммиты с удаленного репозитория, при нажатии на зеленую произойдет коммит в локальную ветку (при коммите опционально можно выбрать и push, либо сделать его позже через меню VCS->git->push).

Чтобы продолжать работу вам не обязательно каждый раз стягивать обновления (но все же желательно, если вы не работаете над задачей в отдельной ветке уже пару дней, хотя и тут следует договориться с командой о workflow).

#### Обновление #1

Что касается настройки, попробуйте так:

1. Убедитесь, что [phpstorm настроен](http://clip2net.com/s/3d78IEJ) на работу с git локально
2. Если кнопки не появились, то убедитесь, что шторм знает о том, что [проект под git-ом](http://clip2net.com/s/3d7mvBu)
3. Перезапустите IDE
4. Убедитесь, что [тулбары видимы](http://c2n.me/3d7nHAF)

Какого-то специального способа добавления папки с git репозиторием в phpstorm - нету. Обычно, при открытии такой папки phpstorm сам все понимает. Т.е. просто File->Open Directory

#### Обновление #2

> Допустим, сделал я изменения в
> каком-то файле и хочу эти изменения
> отправить на сервер - какие мои
> действия? Как быть, если другой...

Когда ваш phpstorm начнет распознавать git репозитории, то часть ваших вопросов отпадет автоматически. При добавлении нового файла в проект, вам будет задан вопрос: "Добавить ли этот файл в репозиторий?" и будет помечен зеленым цветом. Если вы изменили файл, то он поменяет цвет на голубой. Все файлы, которые находятся за пределами контроля версий будут отмечены красным. Белым отмечаются файлы, равные локальной версии ветки репозитория.

Когда вы закончили работу над какой-то задачей, нажмите Ctrl+K (либо на зеленую стрелку), введите комментарий и поменяйте "Commit" на "Commit & Push" - таким образом ваши изменения улетят на сервер и ваш товарищ сможет их стянуть.

Comment: Как можно добавить папку проекта, где git в шторм? Создать как новый проект?

Comment: У меня версия 8.0.1, такие кнопки не появились - но есть меню VCS

Comment: Допустим, сделал я изменения в каком-то файле и хочу эти изменения отправить на сервер - какие мои действия? Как быть, если другой человек тоже сделал тоже изменения и я получаю их с сервера, как сопоставить с моими?

Comment: Что касается настройки, попробуйте так:

 1. Убедитесь, что [phpstorm настроен][1] на работу с git локально
 2. Если кнопки не появились, то убедитесь, что шторм знает о том, что [проект под git-ом][2]
 3. Перезапустите IDE
 4. Убедитесь, что [тулбары видимы][3]


Какого-то специального способа добавления папки с git репозиторием в phpstorm - нету. Обычно, при открытии такой папки phpstorm сам все понимает. Т.е. просто File->Open Directory

  [1]: http://c2n.me/3d7lQXh
  [2]: http://clip2net.com/s/3d7mvBu
  [3]: http://c2n.me/3d7nHAF

Comment: Честно сказать, запутался. На репозитории хранится текущий проект`(dev)` над которым работают несколько человек.
На сервера хранится `production` версия, как можно из dev отгружать некоторые файлы/папки на `production` версию?

Comment: @Vasile, обновил ответ. Из ваших формулировок я вижу, что вам в целом тяжелова-то понять работу git-а. Вы ранее с ним сталкивались? Если нет, то почитайте соответствующую литературу. PHPStorm вам не поможет, пока вы не знаете, как работать с git репозиторием

Answer (score 2):

> Как можно добавить папку проекта, где git в шторм? Создать как новый проект?

На текущий момент времени в PHPStorm из коробки нет поддержки удобного интерфейса по работе с Bitbucket (авторизация по логину и паролю, share). Существует неактуальный плагин под 6-ую версию, а потому, я не уверен в корректности его работы.

Как установить из репозитория плагин:

```
 File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories -> Поиск "Bitbucket"
```

Существует возможность [скачать актуальный плагин](https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads) и установить вручную. Для этого:

```
 File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Install plugin from disk
```

Разархивировать не надо.

#### Обновление

Создание git-репозитория:

```
 VCS -> Import Into Version Control -> Create Git Repository
```

или создание git-репозитория + размещение на Bitbucket (станет доступно после установки плагина):

```
  VCS -> Import Into Version Control -> Share project (слева увидите знакомую иконку Bitbucket)
```

Comment: Отсутствия плагина не означает отсутствия поддержки bitbucket-a, не вводите @Vasile в заблуждение.

Будь то github или bitbucket - это все git репозитории, и если публичный ключ пользователя добавлен на этих сайтах, то плагин совершенно не нужен.

Comment: > Будь то github или bitbucket - это все git репозитории

@likerRr, я это знаю.

ТС спрашивал как расшарить проект с помощью PHPStorm.

Comment: @romeo и вы ответили, что ему нужен плагин, который к тому же и устаревший.

Comment: @likerRr, читайте внимательнее. Я указал на [актуальный](https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads), который требуется установить вручную. Кроме того, уже апробировал.

Comment: @likerRr, а так я с Вами согласен

> PHPStorm вам не поможет, пока вы не знаете, как работать с git репозиторием...

Comment: @romeo, вы правы, про актуальный не обратил внимание. Но я в целом не согласен с вашей формулировкой, что PHPStorm не поддерживает из коробки работу с Bitbucket. Лучше переформулировать, что он не поддерживает авторизацию по логину и паролю и не имеет UI для работы с Bitbucket. 

Ваш ответ, возможно, прочитает не только ТС и увидев фразу "не поддерживает" с большой вероятностью выберет другую IDE.

Ну и в конце концов вопрос про работу с git репозиторием в phpstorm и лишь тэг `bitbucket` указывает на то, где этот репозиторий хостится

Comment: Ребята - открою еще один новый вопрос по настройке git на сервере.

Comment: @likerRr Подправил

Answer (score 0):

Вы, конечно, спрашиваете про phpstorm, но если вы работаете над проектом один и у вас нет необходимости в частом слиянии веток разных версий, то удобнее всего пользоваться командной строкой.

Чтобы отправить на сервер понадобится всего 2 комманды, собственно `commit`  и `push`. Не надо бояться командной строки, тем более что на официальной странице git есть более чем подробнее описание всех команд и неплохие обучалки, если вы захотите познакомиться с этой системой плотнее.